# NoMethodError: undefined method `wepay' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x0000557f33d52d18>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, wepay

I am currently trying to deploy using capistrano, but keep running into this deployment error:

Caused by:

```
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host : rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `wepay' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x0000557f33d52d18>
```

I am using the `wepay` gem in the application, and also have a credential with the name of `wepay`, so I am not sure which this is suggesting is the problem.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my `production.rb` I needed to remove this configuration line:

```
config.wepay.use_stage = true
```